# Change fragment from webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, android-webview

In an application, I use webviews, I would like to make a link in the  page changing the fragment. Is it feasible? If yes, how can it be done? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an implementation for [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29). You'll have to setup a `WebViewClient` for your webview and inside of this method, you'll need to have some logic that recognized that link and then open the new `Activity`. Something like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(isURLMatching(url)) {
                    openNextActivity();
                    return true;
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
    }

    protected boolean isURLMatching(String url) {
            // some logic to match the URL would be safe to have here
        return true;
    }

    protected void openNextActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29